# Swift 3 Method from Class not working with #selector syntax

Tags: swift

I feel as though I'm not understanding the Swift `#selector`s properly. I'm trying to connect a button to a method from another class.

I have a class to print the button when pushed:

```
class printThings {
    @IBAction func printMe(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("Button Pushed.")
    }
}
```

And then the ViewController:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func ViewDidLoad(){
         super.viewDidLoad()
    //button setup here
    let printMe = printThings()
    button.addTarget(printMe, action: #selector(printMe.printMe(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    //add button to subview
    }
}
```

This never triggers the print statement in the class. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `printMe` is a temporary, local variable:

```
let printMe = printThings() // local variable
button.addTarget(printMe, action: #selector(printMe.printMe(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
// ... and then viewDidLoad ends, and `printMe` vanishes
```

So by the time you push the button, `printMe` has vanished; there is no one to send the button message to.

If you want this to work, you need to make `printMe` persist:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let printMe = printThings() // now it's a _property_ and will persist
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //button setup here
        button.addTarget(self.printMe, action: #selector(self.printMe.printMe(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        //add button to subview
    }
}
```